# Laravel save image using dropzone.js into MySQL

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, dropzone.js

I'm just trying out dropzone for the first time and would need assistance to set it up. I am getting error 500 thus:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is the controller:

```
public function storeDocument(Request $request){

         $file = $request->file('file');
         $fileName = uniqid().$file->getClientOriginalName();
         $file->move('gallery/images', $fileName);

         $productVerificationValidation = ProductVerificationValidation::findOrFail($request->productDocumentNameId);
         $documentsUploaded = $productVerificationValidation->productDocumentUpload()->create([
                'gallery_id'    =>  $request->productDocumentNameId,
                'user_id'       =>  Auth::user()->id,
                'company_id'    =>  $request->company_id,
                'product_id'    =>  $request->product_id,
                'file_name'     =>  $fileName,
                'file_size'     =>  $file->getClientSize(),
                'file_mime'     =>  $file->getClientMimeType(),
                'file_path'     =>  'gallery/images'. $fileName
            ]);
    }
```

This is the route to store  the image credentials:

```
Route::post('product/document/upload/save', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'ProductVerificationValidationController@storeDocument'));
```

This is the form for Dropzone:

```
<form action="{{url('product/document/upload/save' )}}" 
                        class="dropzone  first-input-div" id="addImages">{{csrf_field()}} 
                        {!!Form::hidden('productDocumentNameId', $productVerificationValidation->id)!!}
                        {!!Form::hidden('product_id', $productVerificationValidation->product_id)!!}
                        {!!Form::hidden('company_id', $productVerificationValidation->company_id)!!}</form>
```

This is the model setup:

```
public function productDocumentUpload(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductDocumentUpload');
    }
```

I'm yet to understand what I need to do right. Please help out.

Comment: Are you using any sort of browser developer tool (Firebug etc) to see the actual output from the server instead of just how dropzone sees the error?  Laravel should be giving you more details to the error.

Comment: Also, for the form code in your view, I believe you'll need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ??